# Convert 24 hour clock with colon string to minutes with PHP?

Tags: php, string, time, integer

Using PHP, I need to convert a string from my database that is actually a 24 hour clock time with a colon.

Examples:

```
00:30
01:15
03:59
```

Should be the following integers that represent minutes.

```
30
75
239
```

Please, what is the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Well, it's probs too late to suggest this now, but use mysql time or timestamp, rather than "text".

Comment: @James Probably not OP's case, but I once had to work with "later than 24 hour" times in a transit scheduling project. I needed a function to calculate timestamps from times like "24:36" and "25:04" there, which is what you can use a function like this for.

Comment: With hindsight I would of. It came from a JSON and I was I am quite new to coding.

Comment: It's ok that you have chosen user Overv's answer but I would suggest you that take a look at my answer too, because it's a good practice to check for data integrity before returning a result. Keep Overv's answer but add that conditional and you won't have any future error with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to simply split the string:

```
function get_minutes($time_string) {
    $parts = explode(":", $time_string);

    $hours = intval($parts[0]);
    $minutes = intval($parts[1]);

    return $hours * 60 + $minutes;
}
```

For example:

```
print(get_minutes("3:20"));
```

Prints `200`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function totalMinutes($time) {
    $aux = explode(":", $time);
    if(count($aux) == 2){
        return ($aux[0] * 60) + $aux[1];
    }
    else{return 0;}
}

echo totalMinutes("03:59"); //239

echo totalMinutes("bad data"); //0
```